# Are there any estimates for what percentage of the jobs lost this spring are "permanent" at least for the rest of the year?

Tags: reference-request, labor-economics, unemployment, covid-19-crisis

In a "view from the helicopter" [video](https://youtu.be/XsArdIXgRTU?t=119) by *The Economist* on the aftereffects of Covid-19, one of the editors says that it's very unlikely we'll see a return to normal this year e.g. in the restaurant business, even if lockdowns are officially ended. (I suspect air travel business is in a similar situation. Also of some interest, [WSJ video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s7-Y629PvAI) on job losses in the US healthcare sector said to normally be "recession proof"; that video also says some of these [US healthcare] jobs are unlikely to return.)

So are there any attempts to estimate how many of the jobs lost this spring are "permanent" at least for the rest of the year, despite the prognosis of a V-shaped recovery that some/many predict?

I'm not asking about a particular country, but I suspect the US, Europe or China are the places most likely to have such studies/estimates. I'm mainly interested in models for how such an issue could even be estimated, this is why I'm not very particular about the country.

Comment: What's wrong with this question?

Comment: I think your question is okay, sometimes people downvote without any reason.

Comment: People have opinions on this Question. This website is not supposed to be a forum for opinions, as there are plenty of other places to get those.

Comment: @BrianRomanchuk: I guess what you mean by that is that this can't be seriously modeled (because otherwise people have [more or less informed] opinions about many other things, some of which can be reasonably predicted.)

Comment: There is too much uncertainty here (when will any vaccines/treatments be available? how effective will they be? how quickly can they be produced and distributed? how will governments, businesses, and people respond?). The uncertainty involved in this question is similar to asking in normal times whether the world economy will be in a recession five years from today. One can produce answers to such questions, but they'll have such large margins of errors and be so riddled with *ifs* and *buts* that such questions are not suitable for this site.